# Asp.Net MVC dropdownlist using ASCII in text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ascii, dropdown

Is there any way to force MVC to not escape the & on an ASCII value?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.IngredientList.ElementAt(i).AmountId, Model.Amounts, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In the database Amounts are

```
Id   Value
6    &#189;
9    &#190;
```

MVC generates the following select list.

```
<option value="6">&amp;#189;</option>
<option value="9">&amp;#190;</option>
```

I want the following.

```
<option value="6">&#189;</option>
<option value="9">&#190;</option>
```

So that the user sees ½ and ¾ in the dropdown.

**Update:**
the following code works, but you lose the binding to the data model.

```
<select>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Amounts.Count; i++)
{
    <option value="@Model.Amounts.ElementAt(i).Value">@Html.Raw(Model.Amounts.ElementAt(i).Text)</option>
}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try some jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('select option').each(function(){
   $repl = $(this).text().replace('amp;','');
   $(this).text($repl);
  });    
});
```

Comment: While this does replace the amp; it does not display correctly as the select has already been rendered on the screen.